# Why does jQuery does not accept my #ID from the array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, datepicker

I'm trying to add 3 datepickers to 3 of my Input Fields so I am echoeing the following code:

This one works:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#newnessdate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: \'yy-mm-dd\',
        monthNames: [\'Januar\',\'Februar\',\'März\',\'April\',\'Mai\',\'Juni\',\'Juli\',\'August\',\'September\',\'Oktober\',\'November\',\'Dezember\'],
        dayNames: [\'Sonntag\', \'Montag\', \'Dienstag\', \'Mittwoch\', \'Donnerstag\', \'Freitag\',\'Samstag\'],
        dayNamesMin: [\'So\', \'Mo\', \'Di\', \'Mi\', \'Do\', \'Fr\', \'Sa\']
    });
});

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#availabilitydate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: \'yy-mm-dd\',
        monthNames: [\'Januar\',\'Februar\',\'März\',\'April\',\'Mai\',\'Juni\',\'Juli\',\'August\',\'September\',\'Oktober\',\'November\',\'Dezember\'],
        dayNames: [\'Sonntag\', \'Montag\', \'Dienstag\', \'Mittwoch\', \'Donnerstag\', \'Freitag\',\'Samstag\'],
        dayNamesMin: [\'So\', \'Mo\', \'Di\', \'Mi\', \'Do\', \'Fr\', \'Sa\']
    });
});

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#expirydate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: \'yy-mm-dd\',
        monthNames: [\'Januar\',\'Februar\',\'März\',\'April\',\'Mai\',\'Juni\',\'Juli\',\'August\',\'September\',\'Oktober\',\'November\',\'Dezember\'],
        dayNames: [\'Sonntag\', \'Montag\', \'Dienstag\', \'Mittwoch\', \'Donnerstag\', \'Freitag\',\'Samstag\'],
        dayNamesMin: [\'So\', \'Mo\', \'Di\', \'Mi\', \'Do\', \'Fr\', \'Sa\']
    });
});
```

This does not:

```
var dateIds = [
    "#newnessdate", 
    "#availabilitydate",
    "#expirydate"
];

for (var i = 0; i < dateIds.length; i++)
{
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery(dateIds[i]).datepicker({
            dateFormat: \'yy-mm-dd\',
            monthNames: [\'Januar\',\'Februar\',\'März\',\'April\',\'Mai\',\'Juni\',\'Juli\',\'August\',\'September\',\'Oktober\',\'November\',\'Dezember\'],
            dayNames: [\'Sonntag\', \'Montag\', \'Dienstag\', \'Mittwoch\', \'Donnerstag\', \'Freitag\',\'Samstag\'],
            dayNamesMin: [\'So\', \'Mo\', \'Di\', \'Mi\', \'Do\', \'Fr\', \'Sa\']
        });
    });
}
```

I have tested it a lot and don't get it why it not works but in the line

```
jQuery(dateIds[i]).datepicker({
```

it seems, the jQuery function does not accept the strings from the array as strings. Can you help me?

Comment: You have way too many `jQuery(function(){` statements.

Comment: '#epages_expirydate' is not dateIds[i], since dateIds[i] is '#expirydate'. perhaps you wanted `jQuery('#epages'+dateIds[i]).datepicker({` and dateIds without the "#"? (I suppose that the HTML structure is the exact same for both scripts)

Comment: How is any of that working with all those syntax errors?

Comment: oh sry, i changed my problem to make it simple and forgot to remove the "epages_". It was just for simplify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#newnessdate, #availabilitydate, #expirydate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: \'yy-mm-dd\',
            monthNames: [\'Januar\',\'Februar\',\'März\',\'April\',\'Mai\',\'Juni\',\'Juli\',\'August\',\'September\',\'Oktober\',\'November\',\'Dezember\'],
            dayNames: [\'Sonntag\', \'Montag\', \'Dienstag\', \'Mittwoch\', \'Donnerstag\', \'Freitag\',\'Samstag\'],
            dayNamesMin: [\'So\', \'Mo\', \'Di\', \'Mi\', \'Do\', \'Fr\', \'Sa\']
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This is a more jQuery-ish way of doing it. :)

Comment: Wow thanks, this is a way easier and shorter solution. Even though my real problem was, the too many uses of "jQuery(function(){...})"

Comment: :-D jQuery is fun when you realize the many ways you can select things!

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that the loop is finished when the callback is called, and the value of `i` is the one of end of loop.

Simple fix (with the added benefit of not multiplying the calls to `$.ready`) :

```
jQuery(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < dateIds.length; i++)
    {
            jQuery(dateIds[i]).datepicker({
                dateFormat: \'yy-mm-dd\',
                monthNames: [\'Januar\',\'Februar\',\'März\',\'April\',\'Mai\',\'Juni\',\'Juli\',\'August\',\'September\',\'Oktober\',\'November\',\'Dezember\'],
                dayNames: [\'Sonntag\', \'Montag\', \'Dienstag\', \'Mittwoch\', \'Donnerstag\', \'Freitag\',\'Samstag\'],
                dayNamesMin: [\'So\', \'Mo\', \'Di\', \'Mi\', \'Do\', \'Fr\', \'Sa\']
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8LQz2/)

```
var dateIds = [
    "#newnessdate", 
    "#availabilitydate",
    "#expirydate"
];

var options = {
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    monthNames: ['Januar','Februar','März','April','Mai','Juni','Juli','August','September','Oktober','November','Dezember'],
    dayNames: ['Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag','Samstag'],
    dayNamesMin: ['So', 'Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa']
};

$.each(dateIds, function(k, v) {
    $(v).datepicker(options); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According documentation "jQuery(callback)" is analog of "jQuery(document).ready(callback)". You lose context (loop iterator "i"), so then better do it like this:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var dateIds = [
        "#newnessdate", 
        "#availabilitydate",
        "#expirydate"
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < dateIds.length; i++)
    {
        jQuery(dateIds[i]).datepicker({
            .......
        });
    }
});
```

It saves loop context and prevents creation of multiple event (document ready) listeners. If you need to access to array data from global context, just place it outside callback function, but using of global context for store data is bad practice.